# How to make bottom half of a page take up remaining height?

Tags: css

I've searched and tried a bunch of different things.  I have a **variable-height** tophalf, and the bottom half should fill up the remaining space.  A JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UCJmQ/

CSS:

```
.top {
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}
.bottom {
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="bottom">

</div>
```

What I'm seeing now is the green page taking up the entire window's height, not the remaining height.  How can I make it take the remaining height instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ph35V/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        300px
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        Remaining height
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.top {
    display: table-row;
    background: lightblue;
    height: 300px;
}
.bottom {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
```

Could also use [box-sizing: border-box](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) or [conflicting absolute positions](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions)

Comment: Thanks for this.  What if the content of the bottom half is also variable height?  How do I account for the possibility that the bottom half should offer more space than 100% because of overflow?

Answer (score 0):

Is that **variable-height** specified in CSS or not?

From the fiddle I assume it is. If that's the case, try `position: absolute` with `left, bottom, right` set to `0` and `top` to upper div height:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2f9XS/)